# iPhone6's sizes in Unity setup

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I am making a unity application for iPhone6.

For sizes, I refer [here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) and [here](http://www.iosres.com/index-legacy.html).

So I chose iPhone5 Tall(9:16) option.
Then all images are prepared with 326 pixels/inch resolution.
Is that correct?

I just want to make sure so that I don't need to change in the later time.

Since this is my first time for iPhone app, I like to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Make sure that all images are 9:16 aspect ration, now, have different images with different resolution, by maintaining the aspect ratio

Comment: Thank you. yeah we need to keep that aspect ratio.